# Lync API - is it possible to add saved conversation history to a chat window when its opened?

Tags: c#, lync-2013

Lync conversation history is blocked by corporate policy, but I've found a client side library whcih can hook into the messages as they arrive and save them to a file. Great.

What I'd like to know is if its possible to fill the conversation window with some of this saved history when the conversation window is opened with that person again.

The Conversation.BeginMerge option seems promising but you need a conversation to merge in, and the only way I can see to create a conversation actually starts a conversation again (ie starts sending messages) and even afterwards when I call the merge method nothing seems to get merged in, I just seem to get an error in the lync conversation window

So is it possible to 'backfill' the conversation window with some history when the conversation window starts up, but not to resend all those messages?

Comment: What client side library are you using to do this?  Just the Lync SDK?

Comment: this one: https://github.com/bujocek/LyncIMLocalHistory